# How can get the clicked value in multiple select2 jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

```
$(document.body).on('change','.product-dropdown',function(){
   var selectVaule = $(this).val();
   if(selectVaule){
      alert(selectVaule+ 'select');
   }
});
```

Above code return the all selected value in array. I want only get the latest click value on multiple select 2.

Answer (score 11):

look at the `select2:select` event and use the `event.params.data`

There is also a `select2:unselect` too.

```js
$('select').select2()

$('select').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  var data = e.params.data;
  console.log(data.id);
  console.log(data.text);
});

$('select').on('select2:unselect', function(e) {
  var data = e.params.data;
  console.log(data.id);
  console.log(data.text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select multiple="multiple">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">foo</option>
  <option value="2">bar</option>
  <option value="3">foo bar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. This should be selected as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as far as I know there is no elegant solution to this.

Basically just keep track of all values and see which ones are new (note that lastClicked can be a list because it is possible to select multiple values at once):

```
var lastClicked= null;
var prevClicked = [];

$('.product-dropdown').change(function(){
    var curClicked = this.val();
    lastClicked = curClicked.filter(function(x) { return prevClicked.indexOf(x) < 0 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
Got the point what you are saying. But above code still returning the array of all selected values.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        var prevClicked = [];
        var curClicked = [];
        var difference = [];

        $('.product-dropdown').change(function(){
            curClicked = $(this).val();
            if(curClicked == null){
                curClicked=[];
            }
            clickType = getClickType();
            var clickedValue = diffArray(curClicked, prevClicked);
            console.log(clickType + ' ' + clickedValue);

            prevClicked = curClicked;

        });

        function getClickType(){
            var prevLen = prevClicked.length;
            var CurLen = curClicked.length;
            if(prevLen < CurLen){
                return 'select';
            }
            else{
                return 'unselect';
            }
        }

        function diffArray(a1, a2) {
            var a = [], diff = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
                a[a1[i]] = true;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
                if (a[a2[i]]) {
                    delete a[a2[i]];
                } else {
                    a[a2[i]] = true;
                }
            }
            for (var k in a) {
                diff.push(k);
            }
            return diff;
        }
```